# Metric Tensor Identity Manipulation

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor

If I take the metric identity in 4d minkowski spacetime

$$ g_{uv}\frac{dx^u}{d\tau}\frac{dx^v}{d\tau}=1, $$ where $\tau$ is proper time parameterisation. Can I conclude that 
$$4=g^{uv}\frac{d\tau}{dx^u}\frac{d\tau}{dx^v} ? $$

I'm just not sure whether i'm breaking any rules with this kind of manipulation.

Comment: what's $\text d\tau/\text dx^u$?

Comment: ${\left(\frac{dx^u}{d\tau}\right)^{-1}}$

Comment: Do you mean to have a 1 the first time, and a 4 the second time, because if so, then it's definitely wrong because there are counterexamples.

Comment: I used $g_{uv}g^{uv} = 4$ where $g_{uv}$ is the minkowski metric

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't make a mistake, then your technique should work for every coordinate system and for any curve.  So let's look at the simplest of both.

The simplest metric is diagonal and constant, with each entry $\pm1$, and not changing anywhere or anywhen.

The simplest curve is a straight line, aligned with a coordinate axis.  I can't tell what sign conventions you are using, so I'll do a timelike curve having positive length $g^{00}=1$ (though the same idea works for either convention).  So consider the curve $x(t)=(t,0,0,0)$.

Now we have $g^{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}$ (not as a tensor equation, but in the sense that the metric tensor in this basis is diagonal with unit sized real eigenvalues, so is it's own matrix inverse).

Since it is diagonal, the sum in $g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}$ only has four nonzero terms in the metric, and we get:

$$g_{00}\frac{dx^0}{d\tau}\frac{dx^0}{d\tau}+g_{11}\frac{dx^1}{d\tau}\frac{dx^1}{d\tau}+g_{22}\frac{dx^2}{d\tau}\frac{dx^2}{d\tau}+g_{33}\frac{dx^3}{d\tau}\frac{dx^3}{d\tau},$$

which equals (in this very simplest of examples)

$$1*1*1+(-1)*0*0+(-1)*0*0+(-1)*0*0=1.$$

So it all checks out.  But notice that the other equation you have yields the exact same arthimetic since (for this simplest of examples)

$g_{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\nu}$ and $\frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}=\frac{d\tau}{dx^\nu}$, again not as tensor equations, but numerically.

So since $4\neq1$, your result fails to hold for the simplest possible example.  I can't tell what you did, so I can't tell you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Start with your first eq
$$g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d \tau}\frac{d x^\nu}{d \tau}=1$$
It is known that this equivalents with
$$g_{\mu\nu}{dx^\mu}{d x^\nu}= d\tau^2 \equiv g_{\mu\nu}{dx^\mu}\otimes{d x^\nu}= g =ds^2$$
They are (0,2) tensor. They have 2 slot for 2 vectors to gives a scalar value (a component of metrictensor if you insert the coordinate basis). So
$$d\tau^2(\partial_\mu, \partial_\nu)=g(\partial_\mu, \partial_\nu)=g_{\mu\nu}$$
Done in the both sides of second eq implies
$$ g_{\mu\nu}{dx^\mu}\otimes{d x^\nu}(\partial_\alpha,\partial_\beta)=d\tau^2(\partial_\alpha, \partial_\beta) $$
This is nothing but
$$g_{\alpha\beta}=g_{\alpha\beta}$$

But you can define (if you want)
$$d\tau^2(\partial_\alpha, \partial_\beta)=:\frac{d\tau}{dx^\alpha}\frac{d\tau}{dx^\beta}$$
so
$$g_{\alpha\beta}=\frac{d\tau}{dx^\alpha}\frac{d\tau}{dx^\beta}$$
and you will get what you want.